# Command-line pivot a long table into a wide table

Tags: awk, csvfix

How can I turn a long table like

```
Room,"Variable Name",Value
Bedroom,Temperature,23
Bedroom,Humidity,78
Office,Temperature,26
Office,Humidity,82
Bathroom,Temperature,18
Bathroom,Humidity,97
```

Into a wide table like

```
Room,Temperature,Humidity
Bedroom,23,78
Office,26,82
Bathroom,18,97
```

At the command line?

I've tried via `csvfix flatten -smq` but that produces

```
Room,"Variable Name",Value
Bedroom,Temperature,23,Humidity,78
Office,Temperature,26,Humidity,82
Bathroom,Temperature,18,Humidity,97
```

Comment: If you are okay with building the header manually, try `tail -n +2 ip.csv | datamash -t, -g1 collapse 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{
    key = $1
    hdr = ( NR == 1 ? $1 : $2 )

    rowNr = key2row[key] = ( key in key2row ? key2row[key] : ++numRows )
    colNr = hdr2col[hdr] = ( hdr in hdr2col ? hdr2col[hdr] : ++numCols )

    vals[rowNr,1] = key
    vals[1,colNr] = hdr
    vals[rowNr,colNr] = $3
}
END {
    for ( rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++ ) {
        for ( colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++ ) {
            printf "%s%s", vals[rowNr,colNr], (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Value,Temperature,Humidity
Bedroom,23,78
Office,26,82
Bathroom,18,97
```

Comment: I've tried to general-case this and asked for review on codereview.SE. I'd really appreciate any feedback or tips you may have the time to offer: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/290892/98809

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have this file:

```
$ cat file
Room,"Variable Name",Value
Bedroom,Temperature,23
Bedroom,Humidity,78
Office,Humidity,82
Bathroom,Temperature,18
Office,Temperature,26
Bathroom,Humidity,97
```

(Note that the rooms are not in order and Temp and Humidity are in different orders...)

You can use a Ruby like this:

```
ruby -F, -lane '
BEGIN{h=Hash.new{|h,k| h[k]={} }; header=$<.readline }
h[ $F[0] ][ $F[1] ]=$F[2]
END{
    fields=h.values.map{|x| x.keys}.flatten.to_set.to_a
    puts (["Room"]+fields).join(",")
    h.keys.zip(h.
        map{|k,v| v.sort_by{|k,v| fields.find_index(k)}.map(&:last)}).
        each{|l| puts ([l[0]]+l[1..]).join(",") }
}
' file
```

Prints:

```
Room,Temperature,Humidity
Bedroom,23,78
Office,26,82
Bathroom,18,97
```